# Read amount of I/Os in code

Tags: pins, digital

I want to write an Arduino code, that runs on several different Boards. The code can perform digitalRead/Write operations, but the pin number will be set from the user/outside. I want to include a check, if the selected pin exists.

Is it possible, to read the amount of I/Os (digital and analog) of the Arduino the code is currently running on, to check if the users selection is in the given range? Or is it possible to check, if a certain pin number exists?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the core, but most provide the macro `NUM_DIGITAL_PINS` which tells you the number of digital pins the board has.  In general this doesn't equate to the actual number, but to one more than the highest number (there are boards with gaps in the pin number sequence).

So you can use:

```
if (pinNumber < NUM_DIGITAL_PINS) {
    digitalWrite(pinNumber, HIGH);
} else {
    Serial.println("Invalid pin number");
}
```

In tandem with that you also usually have `NUM_ANALOG_INPUTS`.

Answer (score 0):

The number of the GPIO pins available depends on how the chip is wired on the Arduino Board and which microcontroller one is running on. For example, an Arduino Uno with a ATMega328p chip has 14 Digital I/O pins, whereas an Arduino Mega 2560 with a chip has 54 digital I/O pins.